# mensagem de erro Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only

Tags: angular

Estou tendo essa mensagem de erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta indicando que o erro se encontra aqui;

```
<!-- INíCIO do CONTEÚDO -->
<section class="content-header">
  <h1>
    Todos os Restaurantes
  </h1>
</section>


<section class="content">

  <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

          <mt-restaurant [restaurant]="restaurant"></mt-restaurant>

        </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Essa é minha classe de serviços;

```
@Injectable()
export class RestaurantService {
  public url: String = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  //  this.url = environment.url;
   }

   restaurants(): Observable<Restaurant[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants`)
    .map(response => response.json())
  }
```

E essa é minha classe de componentes;

```
  restaurants: Restaurant[]

  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.restaurants()
    .subscribe(restaurants =>  this.restaurants = restaurants)
  }
```

O que pode está havendo de errado?

Comment: Você está passando <mt-restaurant [restaurant]="restaurant"></mt-restaurant> 
"restaurant" e não "restaurants" que é o seu array.

Comment: Parceiro, dá um console.log no teu subscriber do restaurants e vê o que está retornando, e diz aqui pra mim, ou printa pra gente ver melhor o erro. Dá um log tbem no teu observable e printa pra gente analisar e te ajudar melhor, abraços

Comment: ps: essa Http não é o do angular, mas provavelmente um serviço de HTTP feito "na mão" pelo autor da pergunta. Pegadinha pros leitores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando "restaurant" e não "restaurants" que é o seu array.

```
<mt-restaurant [restaurant]="restaurant"></mt-restaurant>
```

Substitua por

```
    <mt-restaurant [restaurant]="restaurants"></mt-restaurant>
```

Comment: Ainda está apresentando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pode publicar o código do mt-restaurant? Como está o input dele?@
@Input() restaurant , essa variável no caso

Comment: acabei de corrigir a postagem.

Comment: meu projeto completo está aqui

Comment: https://github.com/wladyband/restaurant_MEAN/tree/master/src/app/restaurant

Comment: Poderia dá uma olhada para mim por favor?

Comment: só um minuto...

Comment: Pode me mandar um print de como está o console do teu json-server ? eu clonei aqui o projeto e funcionou modificando o caminho de acesso do json-server para public url: String = 'http://localhost:3000';

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79563/discussion-between-lucas-brogni-and-wladyband).

Comment: O problema não é esse

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou ao fazer essa alteração no código;

```
  restaurants(): Observable<Restaurant[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants`)
    .map(response => response.json().restaurants)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o ngFor espera um array, e está recebendo um objeto Response. O erro está aqui:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.restaurants()
    .subscribe(restaurants =>  this.restaurants = restaurants)
}
```

Você recebe o objeto completo do tipo **Response**, precisa indicar o corpo desse Response para o seu atributo **restaurants**:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.restaurants()
    .subscribe(restaurants =>  this.restaurants = restaurants.body)
}
```

Espero que resolva seu problema.